# Facebook app product localization

Tags: facebook, canvas, localization, payment, facebook-unity-sdk

Hi I am trying to implement localization for each of my facebook products which can be purchased through  a game app inside the facebook canvas. The problem is the documentation does not cover localizing strings which are specifically the title and description of the product.

In one of my product htmls which is scraped by facebook I have this.

```
  <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
  <meta property="og:type" content="og:product" />

  <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US"/>
  <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="fr_FR" />
  <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="es_ES" />

  <meta property="og:title" content="tokens.small" />
  <meta property="og:plural_title" content="Small Coins" />  
  <meta property="og:description" content="10,000 coins" />
  <meta property="og:image" content=<img url> />    

  <meta property="product:price:amount" content="0.99"/>
  <meta property="product:price:currency" content="USD"/>
  <meta property="product:price:amount" content="1.29"/>
  <meta property="product:price:currency" content="NZD"/>
  </head>
```

How / where would I declare the strings to be used for fr_FR in terms of title and description. Thanks and appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

You are using static prices. Instead you could use dynamic prices, so when Facebook asks your server for product price, in the json response you add additionally fields 'title' and 'description' based on user locale.